# Cartoon series about transforming cars

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

Looking for a cartoon tv show from my past.

Like I said in the title it had cars and men in spacesuits/helmets.

Cars can transform  ( No it is not Transformers )

There is a kid and a robot I remember. The robot could also transform into a scooter I think.

And there was a red car that could transform into flying mode vehicle.

I saw the show in the mid to late 80s. I think it saw on SKY or SKY One or some such.
That show helped me learn English. :-) Well that and G.I.Joe and He-Man.

Comment: You are thinking about the "Challenge of the Gobots." Came out before the Transformers. It had the kid riding a scoter that turned into a flying robot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are thinking of ***[M.A.S.K.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.A.S.K._(TV_series))*** (1985–1986). Cars could fly and transform and the robot was also a bike.

> M.A.S.K. (an acronym for "Mobile Armored Strike Kommand") is a special task force led by Matt Trakker, who operate transforming armored vehicles in their ongoing battle against the criminal organization V.E.N.O.M. (an acronym for Vicious Evil Network of Mayhem) with an emphasis on superpowered helmets (called "masks") worn by the characters of both factions.

Comment: bah just beat me was looking for the bike reference

Comment: ohhhh... That theme song!! Thank you so much. Now i gotta go home and gig every single episode from thin air!! :-)

Comment: @Cherubel it was a great series. Also look up visionaries while you are at it.

Comment: I have something of a treat for you, @Cherubel, and all the other fans of the **[theme music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmalZOqtv7A)!**

Comment: @Wikis : I loved that theme music, and that's too awesome.  Thank you.

Comment: I still occasionally listen to the [80s cartoon intros](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdkiKR-yhA0) on Youtube. This one always makes me smile